# OpenVPN --route-up Missing environment variables when passing to script

Tags: vpn, openvpn, environment-variables, iproute2

I'm diving into the glory of OpenVPN and I'm having a bit of trouble manually configuring the routing tables. I'm on Arch Linux.

I know OpenVPN automatically updates the routing tables when connecting but I want to write a script to update them myself. I've learned about OpenVPN's “--route-noexec” argument to prevent the automatic updates and the “--route-up” argument to pass relevant information via environment variables to a script of my choice.

This is where I run into trouble. I'd expect environment variables to be passed to the script, which happens, but it looks like I'm missing a few. Especially the one that lists my remote IP address, (untrusted/trusted_ip I believe) which makes it difficult to set iproute.

The environment variables my scripts receives are as follows:

```
dev_type=tun
proto_1=udp
tun_mtu=1500
script_type=route-up
verb=1
local_port_1=1194
dev=tun0
remote_port_1=1194
PWD=/tmp
daemon=0
SHLVL=1
script_context=init
daemon_start_time=1409367799
daemon_pid=927
daemon_log_redirect=0
link_mtu=1500
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

The command I use to launch my VPN is as follows:

```
sudo openvpn --dev tun --route-noexec --script-security 2 --route-up /tmp/print.sh
```

And finally the script I pass it to reads as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
printenv
```

Does anybody know why I'm missing the variables? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the --route-up script runs after routes are established, perhaps you want the --up script ?

Comment: Nope, already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you should pass also "--config" option? eg.

```
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/vpn.conf --script-security 2 --ifconfig-noexec --route-noexec --up ./netnsvpn-up --route-up ./netnsvpn-up
```

And netnsvpn-up something like:

```
case $script_type in
        up)
                ip netns add vpntun0
                ip netns exec vpntun0 ip link set dev lo up
                ip link set dev "$1" up netns vpntun0 mtu "$2"
env
                ip netns exec vpntun0 ip addr add dev "$1" "${ifconfig_local}"/"${ifconfig_netmask:-30}" 
                ;;
        route-up)
                ip netns exec vpntun0 ip route add default via "$route_vpn_gateway"
                ;;
        down)
                ip netns delete vpntun0
                ;;
esac
```

vpntun0 is the name space.